# Identity $ \epsilon_{abcd} R^{cd}_{\phantom{cd}mn} = \epsilon_{mncd} R^{cd}_{\phantom{cd}ab}$ in vacuum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature

starting from 
\begin{align}
  \epsilon_{\rho\lambda\xi \kappa} R^{\xi \kappa}_{\phantom{ab} \sigma\tau} + \epsilon_{\rho\sigma \xi \kappa} R^{\xi \kappa}_{\phantom{ab} \tau \lambda} + \epsilon_{\rho \tau \xi \kappa} R^{\xi \kappa}_{\phantom{\xi \kappa} \lambda \sigma}=0
\end{align}
The [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1006.3168) says, after some simple algebra with the anti-symmetric properties of $\epsilon_{abcd}$ $R_{abcd}$ one can obtain 
\begin{align}
  \epsilon_{\rho\lambda \xi \kappa} R^{\xi \kappa}_{\phantom{ab} \sigma \tau} = \epsilon_{\sigma \tau \xi \kappa} R^{\xi \kappa}_{\phantom{ab} \rho \lambda}
\end{align}

First my guess was interchange indices $\rho \lambda$ with $\sigma \tau$ with first Bianchi identiy $i.e$ 
\begin{align}
\epsilon_{\rho\lambda\xi \kappa} R^{\xi \kappa}_{\phantom{ab} \sigma \tau}
= \epsilon_{\rho\sigma \xi \kappa} ( R^{\xi \phantom{ab} \kappa}_{\phantom{a} \tau \lambda}+R^{\xi \phantom{a} \kappa\phantom{b}}_{\phantom{a} \lambda\phantom{b} \tau}) + \epsilon_{\rho \tau \xi \kappa} ( R^{\xi \phantom{ab} \kappa}_{\phantom{a} \lambda \sigma}+R^{\xi \phantom{a} \kappa\phantom{b}}_{\phantom{a} \sigma\phantom{b} \lambda})  
\end{align} 
and 
\begin{align}
\epsilon_{\sigma\tau\xi \kappa} R^{\xi \kappa}_{\phantom{ab} \rho \lambda}
= \epsilon_{\sigma\rho \xi \kappa} ( R^{\xi \phantom{ab} \kappa}_{\phantom{a}  \lambda\tau}+R^{\xi \phantom{a} \kappa\phantom{b}}_{\phantom{a} \tau\phantom{b} \lambda}) + \epsilon_{\sigma \lambda \xi \kappa} ( R^{\xi \phantom{ab} \kappa}_{\phantom{a} \tau \rho}+R^{\xi \phantom{a} \kappa\phantom{b}}_{\phantom{a} \rho\phantom{b} \tau})
\end{align}

I can see that the first term of $\epsilon_{\rho\lambda\xi \kappa} R^{\xi \kappa}_{\phantom{ab} \sigma \tau}$ and $\epsilon_{\sigma\tau\xi \kappa} R^{\xi \kappa}_{\phantom{ab} \rho \lambda}$ are equal but the second part seems not equal to each other (it reduce the same form of ideneity we want to prove)

---

The paper says it is simple computation with the anti-symmetric properties of $\epsilon$ and $R$. If you know how to do this can you give me some hint or some idea?

Comment: can you refer to the paper in question?

Comment: The paper i refer is arxiv 1006.3168v2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, operate with $\epsilon^{\sigma\tau\alpha\beta}$
\begin{align}
  \epsilon_{\rho\lambda\xi \kappa} R^{\xi \kappa}_{\phantom{ab} \sigma\tau}\epsilon^{\sigma\tau\alpha\beta} + \epsilon_{\rho\sigma \xi \kappa} R^{\xi \kappa}_{\phantom{ab} \tau \lambda} \epsilon^{\sigma\tau\alpha\beta}+ \epsilon_{\rho \tau \xi \kappa} R^{\xi \kappa}_{\phantom{\xi \kappa} \lambda \sigma}\epsilon^{\sigma\tau\alpha\beta}=0
\end{align}
Then you will have
\begin{eqnarray}
0&=&\epsilon_{\rho\lambda\xi \kappa} R^{\xi \kappa} {}_{\sigma\tau}\epsilon^{\sigma\tau\alpha\beta} + \delta^{\tau\alpha\beta}_{\rho \xi \kappa}R^{\xi \kappa}_{\phantom{ab} \tau \lambda}-\delta^{\sigma\alpha\beta}_{\rho \xi \kappa}  R^{\xi \kappa}_{\phantom{\xi \kappa} \lambda \sigma}\\
&=&\epsilon_{\rho\lambda\xi \kappa} R^{\xi \kappa} {}_{\sigma\tau}\epsilon^{\sigma\tau\alpha\beta} + 2\delta^{\tau\alpha\beta}_{\rho \xi \kappa}R^{\xi \kappa}_{\phantom{ab} \tau \lambda}\quad(1)
\end{eqnarray}

We need 
$$\delta^{\tau\alpha\beta}_{\rho \xi \kappa} = (\delta^\tau_\rho \delta^\alpha_\xi \delta^\beta_\kappa -\delta^\tau_\rho \delta^\alpha_\kappa \delta^\beta_\xi+\delta^\tau_\xi \delta^\alpha_\rho \delta^\beta_\kappa-\delta^\tau_\xi \delta^\alpha_\kappa \delta^\beta_\rho+\delta^\tau_\kappa \delta^\alpha_\xi \delta^\beta_\rho-\delta^\tau_\kappa \delta^\alpha_\rho \delta^\beta_\xi) $$
Then
$$
R^{\xi \kappa}_{\phantom{ab} \tau \lambda}\delta^{\tau\alpha\beta}_{\rho \xi \kappa} = 2 R^{\alpha\beta}{}_{\rho\lambda}
$$
By using this eq (1) becomes
$$
-4  R^{\alpha\beta}{}_{\rho\lambda}
=
\epsilon_{\rho\lambda\xi \kappa} R^{\xi \kappa} {}_{\sigma\tau}\epsilon^{\sigma\tau\alpha\beta}
$$
($$-Riem= \star Riem \star$$
Note that in this language you need only operate both side with Hodge dual the result is
$$\star Riem =Riem \star$$
indeed, the result you want.
)
Back to our main method operate both sides with $\epsilon_{\alpha\beta\mu\nu}$ we have
$$
-4 \epsilon_{\alpha\beta\mu\nu} R^{\alpha\beta}{}_{\rho\lambda}
=
\epsilon_{\rho\lambda\xi \kappa} R^{\xi \kappa} {}_{\sigma\tau}(-2! (\delta^\sigma_\mu \delta^\tau_\nu-\delta^\sigma_\nu \delta^\tau_\mu))
$$
finally
$$
\epsilon_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta} R^{\alpha\beta}{}_{\rho\lambda}
=\epsilon_{\rho\lambda\xi \kappa} R^{\xi \kappa} {}_{\mu\nu}
$$